# How does Drunken Monkey interact with Savage Demise?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

A PC (character A) in our game used **Drunken Monkey** on an enemy (character B). It hit and did the following:

> **Hit**: 1d8 + Dexterity modifier damage, and you slide the target 1 square. The target then makes a melee basic attack as a free action against one enemy of your choice. The target gains a bonus to the attack roll equal to your Wisdom modifier.

The damage is enough to reduce the B's health below 0.

B is an orc and has the power **Savage Demise**:

> Immediate Reaction
>   **Trigger**: You drop to 0 hit points.
>   **Effect**: (Free Action) You take a standard action.

It used this to attack A who killed it.

Does B still make a melee basic attack against another enemy of A's choice as per the description of Drunken Monkey?

As a bonus, does the B's action before death occur before or after the slide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An immediate reaction lets a creature act in response to a trigger. The triggering action or event occurs and is completely resolved before the reaction takes place. An immediate reaction waits for its trigger to finish, not necessarily for the action that contains the trigger to finish.
>    (Rules Compendium, page 196)

1. A hits B for d8+Dex damage. This drops B to 0 HP, killing them and triggering the Immediate Reaction.
2. B takes a standard action as a free action, per their Immediate Reaction. Now back to A's action.
3. B is no longer a valid target, since they're dead. No slide, no additional melee attack as a free action.

Comment: As purely rule based answer this seems perfect. However would it make sense to house rule and modify the outcome of B's standard action. This is because `Drunken Monkey`'s effect would suggest that B is affected temporarily and as an example could take a negative modifier to hit.